# Convert CSV to HTML table in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby, csv, html-table

Does anyone know how to convert a CSV file to an HTML table in Ruby (NOT Ruby on rails)? I cannot find any Ruby gems that can convert CSV to an HTML table in a friendly format. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [built in CSV class](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) to load the CSV file,
for example line by line:

```
CSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv") do |row|
  # use row here...
end
```

And then you can just output it as html yourself:

```
puts "<table>"
CSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv") do |row|
  puts "<tr>"
  # print out all data in row here...
  puts "</tr>"
end
puts "</table>"
```

Or you could use the [table-for gem](https://github.com/hunterae/table-for) or [html-table](https://github.com/djberg96/html-table) to create the table

Comment: `table-for` has a `rails` dependency so probably not the best solution in this case, Your original suggestion of `html-table` was definitely a better option